# How to Merge two classes A and B to define the functions of a abstract class in C++

Tags: c++, class, abstract

In my C++ project, I have an abstract class that defines an interface for a dll.  Call it CAbstractClass.

I have a class AClass which has defined functions for all but 1 of the functions of CAbstractClass.  How do I create a new non-abstract class C to inherit CAbstractClass?

Here's my attempt. It results in the error 'E0322: object of abstract class type "CClass" is not allowed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class CAbstractClass
{
public:
    CAbstractClass(void) {};
    ~CAbstractClass(void) {};

    virtual int Fn1(int a) = 0;
    virtual double Fn2(int a, int b) = 0;
    virtual int Fn3(double a, double b) = 0;
};

class AClass
{
public:
    AClass(void) {};
    ~AClass(void) {};

    int Fn1(int a) { return 2 * a; }
    double Fn2(int a, int b) { return (double)a / (double)b; }
};

class BClass
{
public:
    BClass(void) {};
    ~BClass(void) {};

    int Fn3(double a, double b) { return (int) (a+b); }
};

// My guess at how to combine all the classes.
class CClass : public CAbstractClass, public AClass, public BClass
{
public:
    CClass(void) {};
    ~CClass(void) {};
};


int main()
{
    CClass C;       // E0322: object of abstract class type "CClass" is not allowed.


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AClass` and `BClass` also have to inherit from `CAbstractClass`. Fn1 Fn2 and Fn3 just don't implement virtual methods of abstract class so `CClass` is also abstract

```
class AClass : public CAbstractClass {
//...
};
class BClass : public CAbstractClass {
//...
};
class CClass : public virtual AClass, public virtual BClass {
//...
};
```

Comment: Be sure to use virtual inheritance; otherwise there are two `CAbstractClass` base subobjects in `CClass`, which will cause ambiguous lookups, unexpected behavior, and/or confusion.

Comment: I follow the logic. I made the changes to the code and I still get the same error. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: @user3341576 make sure you have used virtual inheritance.  When I am using gcc, it will complain for pure virtual function in C if I am not using virtual inheritance, for which is reasonable as that 2 `CAbstractClass` sub-objects are still both containing pure virtual function

Comment: In Visual Studio this code with 'class CClass : public virtual AClass, public virtual BClass'  fails with 'E0322: object of abstract class type "C" is not allowed.'  However, using 'public virtual CAbstractClass' on each of ClassA and ClassB instead, gets the code to compile successfully. So that works, but its not desired in my case because class A is part of another project which has nothing to do with CAbstractClass.  It has its own AAbstractClass.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can be done using a single CAbstractClass, but if you split your abstract interface into two separate abstract interfaces, then it is easy enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class CAbstractClassA
{
public:
    virtual int Fn1(int a) = 0;
    virtual double Fn2(int a, int b) = 0;
};

class CAbstractClassB
{
public:
    virtual int Fn3(double a, double b) = 0;
};

class AClass : public CAbstractClassA
{
public:
    int Fn1(int a) { return 2 * a; }
    double Fn2(int a, int b) { return (double)a / (double)b; }
};

class BClass : public CAbstractClassB
{
public:
    int Fn3(double a, double b) { return (int) (a+b); }
};

// My guess at how to combine all the classes.
class CClass : public AClass, public BClass
{
public:
};

int main()
{
    CClass C;
    printf("Fn1(5) returns %i\n", C.Fn1(5));
    printf("Fn2(10,12) returns %f\n", C.Fn2(10,12));
    printf("Fn3(3.14,6.28) returns %i\n", C.Fn3(3.14,6.28));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A single abstract class is required.  It is used as a dll interface.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, perhaps use composition instead?  i.e. make your CClass class hold an AClass object and a BClass object and implement the methods to pass the calls on through to the held objects (and return the held-class's methods' return values back to the caller)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using. I chose it because it leaves AClass alone. There is more work: every member function that comes from AClass must be defined in BClass. Another benefit is that there's no need for a CClass.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class BAbstractClass
{
public:
    BAbstractClass(void) {};
    ~BAbstractClass(void) {};

    virtual int Fn1(int a) = 0;
    virtual double Fn2(int a, int b) = 0;
    virtual int Fn3(double a, double b) = 0;
};

class AClass
{
public:
    AClass(void) {};
    ~AClass(void) {};

    int Fn1(int a) { return 2 * a; }
    double Fn2(int a, int b) { return (double)a / (double)b; }

};



class BClass : public AClass, public BAbstractClass
{
public:
    BClass(void) {};
    ~BClass(void) {};

    int Fn3(double a, double b) { return (int)(a + b); }

    // Define a function for each of AClass' member functions.
    int Fn1(int a) { return AClass::Fn1(a); }
    double Fn2(int a, int b) { return AClass::Fn2(a, b); }

};



int main()
{
    BClass B;

    return 0;
}
```